# django no access-control-allow-origin header on Delete

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

In my Django Rest API Famework, For enable CORS, I'm using the app:

```
corsheaders
```

([django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers))
with the setting:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

which is working fine for `GET`, `POST` and `PATCH`
However, only for `DELETE`, I'm getting this error:

```
no access-control-allow-origin header on the requested resource
```

I'm firing this request from javascript like this:

```
data = {oper:'campaigns', req_type:'dc'};
    $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "DELETE",
            traditional: true,
            datatype:"json",
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
```

I'm not getting any clue why this is happening only for DELETE !!

Comment: what is the status code you're getting?

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://veveoinc.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info here (what is the status code etc...), but try the following on your Ajax request:

```
data: {'_method':'delete'}, 
type: 'POST'
```

Not all browsers support the DELETE method.